# filter on child model attribute in the parent model #activeadmin #json field

Tags: json, activeadmin, ransack

I have 2 models, say, User and UserProfile. User has one UserProfile. The UserProfile has a json column named 'details' with 'age' as one of the keys. I need a filter in the User index page with filtering and sorting available for 'age'. I am using ActiveRecord.

```
User
  has_one :user_profile
  #id: integer
  #email: string

UserProfile
  belongs_to :user
  #user_id: integer
  #details: json

ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :id, as: :numeric
  filter :email, as: :string
  filter :age, as: :numeric
  ...
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @jfoo refer http://prasadsurase.github.io/blog/2016/05/03/filtering-for-json-keys-as-columns/